# MS Access - an error occurred while application was communicating with the OLE server or ActiveX Control

Tags: ms-access, vba

Please help with one issue about MS Access development.

I develop an application in MS Access 2010 Czech installation in Win10 Pro, Czech installation.
Then I use MS Access 2016 and save it in this version as a 64bit version (Czech installation) and the same windows – win10 Pro Czech.

If I run the application in Win10 Pro English installation via MS Access Runtime 2016-64bit an error rise up, see picture below.
I try out a full version of MS Access in this environment and the trouble was still running.

On my computer is working without any error.

PLEASE does anybody any experience in this problem? I am trying to solve out more than a month and it's driving me crazy.

I have got through all threads on Stack Overflow and related links. Nothing helps.

[image]

Comment: You will have to provide far more information for us to be able to help, such as when this happens (when opening a form?) and the code/expressions you're using.

Comment: Looks like your code or names on objects contains Czech characters. Try to copy all objects to new database created in English Access.

Comment: My 2 bits: When I had my system opened in 64Bit, I got a similar error. I recompiled the VBA, and had to work around some of the code, **especially Windows API code**

Comment: Thanks for replays,
I did several tests included to purchase space in cloud server Win serve r2012 R2 64bit and did this step. Create new database – new simple table – new form. 
Without any VBA code this form work properly. Afterwards I added VBA code into event “Before insert” and error comes (error from my title).
So I don’t have any idea what to do.
Code: 
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
   MsgBox "fdsfsadg"
End Sub

Comment: Try to reinstall the Office. Remove it completely before installation.

Comment: I try out nearly everything. At at the end I have found out that the problem is with non-Unicode language. It can be changed in windows in system locale. But trouble is that I need to repair my application from non-Unicode to into Unicode. And here is problem how to do it.